# How to isolate bootstrap CSS and JavaScript to a part of the html page?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been given a website with lots of CSS and JavaScript.
I need to add a toolbar, dialog box, and popper to the web page.
I want to use bootstrap, but there is a conflict with existing CSS.

I see I can [isolate the bootstrap CSS](https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap) to a part of the html:

```
<div class="bootstrap-iso">
  <!-- Any HTML here will be styled with Bootstrap CSS --> 
</div>
```

But what about the JavaScript? (bootstrap dialog boxes requires jQuery and popper.js)

---

**Solution**

I finally decided to use the uikit library, because it has a built-in "custom-prefix" mode and a "scope" mode that solves my two issues:
https://getuikit.com/docs/avoiding-conflicts#scope-mode

Comment: otherwise, is it there any other library with fewer dependencies? (with toolbar, dialog boxes, and poppers)

Comment: Is your CSS and JS conflicting or just CSS?

Comment: I finally decided to use the uikit library, because it has a built-in "custom-prefix" mode and a "scope" mode that solves my two issues:
https://getuikit.com/docs/avoiding-conflicts#scope-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your link is well explained how to do what you want. 
Practically, if you have a css preprocessor you have to import bootstrap css from inside some custom class

```
// LESS preprocessor
.my-custom-class {
  @import (less) 'bootstrap.css';
  @import (less) 'bootstrap-theme.css';
}

// or SASS preprocessor
.my-custom-class{
    @import "bootstrap.scss";
    @import "bootstrap-theme.css";
}
```

as you can find in your link there are problem with some class, because isn't possible to have `.my-custom-class body` or `.my-custom-class html` for this reason you need to replace that class with a text editor

find all `.my-custom-class body` body and replace with `.my-custom-class`
find all `.my-custom-class html` body and replace with `.my-custom-class`

Now all your bootstrap css have a parent class to target only the element inside your wrapper:

```
// this
.embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}

// become
.my-custom-class .embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: i understood the CSS part from the tutorial. what about the javascript part? will bootstrap still work with this modified CSS? and if the page already contains a previous version of bootstrap and/or jquery, how to avoid conflicts?

Comment: the javascript may work also with this modified version, because in a js if you target for example .embed-responsive element isn't important if that is inside other wrapper. For what about eventual conflicts you have to try, depend on your environment.

Comment: I finally decided to use the uikit library, because it has a built-in "custom-prefix" mode and a "scope" mode that solves my two issues:
https://getuikit.com/docs/avoiding-conflicts#scope-mode